# A classifier based on PCA done within classes

Tags: classification, pca, discriminant-analysis, k-nearest-neighbour

Suppose that you want to classify if an unlabeled length $n$ vector $X$ belongs to a class $i=1...I$.

#### Method A:

You have labeled data, so you compute the per class mean $\mu_i$ and covariance matrices $C_i$, as well as the PCA of the $C_i$'s so that you can write a subspace, $V_{i,d}$, from the $d$ top eigenvectors of $C_i$. You can then project $X$ onto a given $\mu_i+V_{i,d}$ subspace: $\rm{Proj}_{i,d}(X)$. Fix $d$. A possible classifier is then $\rm{argmin}_{i=1...I} \lVert X- \rm{Proj}_{i,d}(X) \rVert$.

#### Method B

Another classifier is $\rm{argmin}_{i=1...I} \lVert X- \mu_i \rVert$

#### Method C

Nearest Neighbor search

---

I am interested in comparing these 3 methods, in terms of predictive performance, and I am not interested in minimizing the amount of computation.

My questions:

1. A is like B but ignores the contribution to the distance from the lowest $n-d$ eigen-directions, correct?
2. There is something to gain by doing A over B if you know there is some important linear discriminatory variables between the classes, and some unimportant nonlinear non-discriminatory variables between the classes (hoping to cut the later out with PCA)?
3. When can B perform worse than A, in the opposite scenario I describe in 2?
4. When will C beat A and B?
5. What is method A called and is it well known, or a result of/related to something well known? Can this be related to m-ary hypothesis testing, or some linear discriminant?

Comment: I don't think A deserves a name: you just replace original variables in each class by few strong principal axes in that class. It depends whether this method is "good" or "bad" at the subsequent classifying. Note that in B (distance to class centroid) and C (distance to closest class points) you are distancing your point `x` from the locus/points (centroid or neighbours, respectively) which belong to classes, lie within classes physically. In A, however, you are distancing `x` from its component score, i.e. the place it projects onto a retained component's axis,

Comment: (cont.) but _axis_ is not a bounded thing. Therefore, if `x` happens to be an outlier far way from the rest of points it can be easily assigned by A method to one class while according to B or C methods it is much closer to another class. Classifying newcomer unusual points `x` will be especially prone for that.

Comment: Method C, oppositely, is not optimal if, obviously, the oulier(s) is not `x` but its closest neighbour(s) from one class (such as when the class has some protuberance in the direction of `x`).

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question 2. If some input variable is a relatively strong linear discriminator that means (under general case of spacially close or overlapping classes) the classes - elllipsoids - should be approximately parallel in their orientation and also similar physical size (that is, have similar covariance matrices). That assumption will mean principal axes between all the clouds are near parallel. Then the more these pr. axes are perpendicular to the discriminants of linear discriminant analysis (LDA) the better they can serve as classifiers.

Comment: (cont.)  But in practice they can be more or less perpendicular to them. Thus, if the LDA assumption of covariance matrices homegeneity holds then LDA will generally be more reliable classifier than A. But A is worth considering.